# Why do we first need to unload data from redshift to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am trying to consume some data in redshift using sagemaker to train some model. After some research, I found the best way to do so is first unloading the data from redshift to an S3 bucket. I assume sagemaker has API to directly interact with redshift, but why do we need to first unload it to an S3 bucket?

Comment: "I assume sagemaker has API to directly interact with redshift" - why do you assume that? Any links to docs supporting this assumption?

Comment: Can you just use libraries like pg8000 https://pypi.org/project/pg8000/?

Answer (score 1):

UNLOADing is a best practice and generally the method that the docs will promote.  This is due to efficiency and performance.  Redshift is a cluster with a single leader and multiple compute nodes.  S3 is a cluster - a distributed object store.  Having multiple compute nodes connect to S3 when moving data is far faster and less of a burden to the database.

Also, tools that you may be using with sagemaker (like EMR) are also clusters and will also benefit from multiple parallel connections to S3.

The larger the amount of data being moved the greater this benefit will be.